# woocommerce add order from admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have 4 different users in woocommerce that add order for customer how to differentiate between them on their id like which user add order

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have 4 different users in woocommerce that add order for customer how to differentiate between them on their id like which user add order

Comment: Thank your for your comment, but you should edit your question with your comments accordingly. That makes it more understandable for other users.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with an admin CSS code. If you don't have an admin CSS file you need to create it like explain in this post : https://davidwalsh.name/add-custom-css-wordpress-admin

After file create, to apply a color to your manualy created order, add this css code :

```
#posts-filter > table > #the-list > tr.author-self{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

For others orders :

```
#posts-filter > table > #the-list > tr.author-other{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

You can replace the colors by the hexa code of you choice :)
let me know

Comment: its working but I want different background colors for each user based on there login id so that I can differentiate easily